# Оптимизация большого количества счетчиков

Tags: php, mysql

**Есть разные таблицы в MySql:**
*поддержка, жалобы, удаления, регистрации, сообщения.*

**Есть сайт, в шапке выводятся счетчики реального времени:**
*кол-во обращений в поддержку, кол-во жалоб, кол-во запросов на удаления, кол-во регистраций, кол-во сообщений.*

Все запросы SQL по типу `SELECT COUNT`, иногда с объединениями.

Проблема. Счетчики для каждого пользователя выводятся в режиме реального времени. Получается, при загрузки страницы отправляется большое количество запросов к MYSQL.

Мне не хватает опыта и знаний. Прошу подсказать, как правильно подходить к вопросу, чтобы не нагружать сайт лишними запросами.

**Пришла идея** работы с кроном, который раз в 30 секунд будет запускать метод для подсчета актуальных данных и записывать их в отдельную таблицу БД.

А данные для счетчиков подтягивать из этой таблицы, одним запросом.

Это кажется более правильным, чем подсчитывать по 50-100 тыс. записей с каждого обновления страницы.

**Поделитесь пожалуйста** опытом и мыслями.

Comment: отдельная таблица - денормализация. лучше покопайте в сторону кэша. нет смысла обновлять кроном счётчики всех юзеров. очевидно нужны только активные. просто кэшируйте эти же значения на те же 30 сек и даже без инвалидации получите аналогичный результат

Comment: это как-то можно будет совместить с обновлением данных в таблицах? Например, данные в таблице изменились, но не дожидаясь сброса кеша они должны обновиться.

Comment: @Lexx918 то есть если одни и те же данные положить в файл, то это будет называться "кэш", а если в БД - то "денормализация"? Какая, оказывается, важная штука - терминология. То, как ты назовешь свои бессмысленные телодвижения, оказывается, меняет всю технологию.

Comment: @Ипатьев если разница в значениях терминов не видна, это не значит, что её нет. привет редису, мемкешу, хэндлерсокету и тарантулу. не переживай, понимание придёт с опытом

Comment: @Lexx918 "я знаю бокс, карате, дзюдо, самбо и много других страшных слов"  :)

Answer (score 0):

Поставь индексы на те поля, по которым идёт подсчёт и забудь эти страхи про "большое количество запросов".

Comment: Индексы уже стоят, спасибо. Я наверное не корректно выразился в своем примере, у меня не 5 таких таблиц (это для примера), а около 20. Счетчиков очень много. 1000 запросов при загрузке страницы меня пугает, хоть вы и правильно подметили, индексы очень выручили.

Comment: откуда там тыща запросов? какой пользователь будет разглядывать 1000 цифр? Хорошо, не 5, а 20. Как 20 превратилось в 1000?

Comment: Многие запросы сложные с объединениями и дополнительными подсчетами. Это для модераторов каунтеры

Comment: Вот и займись оптимизацией этих запросов. Надо чтобы запросов было мало и они были оптимальные. Надо учиться писать нормальные запросы, а не выносить все это стадо в крон. Я так и не понял, откуда взялась цифра в 1000 запросов. у тебя запросы в цикле что ли идут? А про GROUP BY ты что-нибудь слышал?

Comment: извини, я конечно привираю, говоря о 1000 запросах, их меньше, но я хотел четко обозначить свою проблему, чтобы не уводили в сторону.

Количество счетчиков реально растёт в нашем проекте и я не хочу доказывать их целесообразность.

И я не спрашивал ничего про медленные запросы, чтобы мне говорили об индексах, также как и не делился SQL запросам для помощи в оптимизации.

Comment: У тебя не получилось. проблемы здесь никакой никто не увидел, только суеверные страхи "большого количества запросов"